# Clojure: Is it possible to execute multiple expressions in a `cond' case?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, is it possible to execute multiple expressions in a *cond* case, without *do* or *let* form. In Racket, one may do things as:

```
(cond
    (> a 0) ((display a) (display (* a a))
    (= a 0) ...
    ...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have you read the documentation of the cond macro? cond and case are different things btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another form that contains an implicit `do` is `when`, so “yes,” you could achieve this without `do` or `let`:

```
(cond
  (> a 0) (when true
            (println a)
            (println (* a a))))
```

But, of course, that's contrived and the real answer to your question is “no.”

Each clause has a pair of forms: A test form and an expression form. You can't have multiple expression forms in a `cond` clause—you'd need to further wrap them in a single form such as `do`. They are referred to as *expression* forms because usually their *value* is of interest (in a purely functional context) because it is the value of the expression in the clause with the first truthy test that the entire `cond` form evaluates to.

But, if you are using `cond` as a way to achieve conditional side effects, perhaps `do` is a good reinforcement of the intent:

```
(cond
  (> a 0) (do (println a)
              (println (* a a))))
```

Comment: What do you mean `side effects'?

Comment: Good question: If you are executing multiple forms, like the multiple `println` calls in your example, you are evaluating each for a reason, and discarding their values. The reason you are executing them is for their side effects. This is in contrast to the way `cond` is often used in a purely functional context: to obtain the value of the expression in the clause containing the first true test. The entire `cond` form evaluates to this value. In this use, `cond` is a conditional way to determine a _value_, as opposed to a conditional way to execute code for side effects.